# How to Fully Hide Modal?

Tags: html

[image: This is My Modal]

[image: After Press Close]

[image: Why 2 time modal show]

```html
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h4>
                <button type="button" id="btn-times" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="content4">
                    <!--- Content ---->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Picture show after I pressing close still got 1 layer block.

I **Create modal inside a collapse** that why the modal show 2 times?

-> if I press close only 1 modal close and 1 still there. (Image 3 I Show)

How to close this all?

Comment: can you show me your html and javascript file?

Comment: Make sure you include bootstrap-js script along with jquery in your file in right order. The correct order is first load jquery and then bootstrap.

Comment: Include your code so we could be able to get more info

Comment: @KaushikMakwana i added some code